# R: how to apply rev() to specific rows

Tags: r

Here is my matrix:

```
df <- data.frame(matrix(1:25,5))

    X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
 1  1  6 11 16 21
 2  2  7 12 17 22
 3  3  8 13 18 23
 4  4  9 14 19 24
 5  5 10 15 20 25
```

I want to apply rev() to some specific rows at row#1 #3 and #5. 
Here is the result I want to get:

```
    X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
 1  21 16 11  6  1
 2   2  7 12 17 22
 3  23 18 13  8  3
 4   4  9 14 19 24
 5  25 20 15 10  5
```

I know how to use rev() to each row to get the reversed series. For example, rev(df[1,]) works for each row. Please let me know how to apply rev() to some specific rows and get desired matrix.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works by extracting the rows you want, reversing them, then writing them back in the same location:

```
df[c(1,3,5),]=rev(df[c(1,3,5),])
```

Answer (score 1):

Or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[c(1,3, 5), names(df) := rev(.SD)]
```